# How to exclude ElementArrayFinder items that exists in another ElementArrayFinder in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I would like to obtain menu-ui items that user is able to click.

Unfortunately, `isEnabled` method returns always `true` for all of my items.
That's why I try another approach. I noticed that disabled ones, always have 'ui-state-disabled' class. As a consequence, I'm able to get all disabled items, using following function:

```
function getDisabledMenuItems() {
  return getCustomGrid().all(by.className('menu-ui')).all(by.className('ui-state-disabled')).all(by.className('menu-item-text'));
}
```

and then all menu items using following one:

```
function getAllMenuItems() {
  return getCustomGrid().all(by.className('menu-ui')).all(by.className('menu-item-text'));
}
```

Now I would like to exclude items returned by `getDisabledMenuItems` from items returned by `getAllMenuItems`.

---

**Question**

What is the easiest way to exclude ElementArrayFinder items that exists in another ElementArrayFinder?

I'm trying to do that by means of `filter` method as follows:

```
const disabledText = getDisabledMenuItems().getText();
const allItems = getAllMenuItems();

  allItems.filter(function(elem, index) {
    return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
      return disabledText.indexOf(text) < 0 ;
    });
  });
```

but my code does not work (`indexOf does not exists on type Promise<string>`).
I also wonder what is the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getDisabledMenuItems().getText()` return a promise, you have to consume its eventual value in `then()`:

```
const disabledText = getDisabledMenuItems().getText();
const allItems = getAllMenuItems();

const enableItems = allItems.filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    return disabledText.then(function(txts){
      return txts.includes(text) === false;
      // or use  return txts.indexOf(text) < 0;
    });
  });
});
```